# Question in solving wave equation by eigenvalue-eigenfuntion

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenfunctions

I am learning to solve PDEs, I found a example the following from a book,

$u_{tt}(x,t)$=$u_{xx}(x,t)$

$u_x(0,t)=0$, $u(L,t)=0$

$u_x(x,0)=\sin\frac{3\pi x}{2}$, $u_t(L,t)=\cos\frac{3\pi x}{2}$.

Now by separating the variables,

$T''(t)+\lambda T(t)=0$,

and a regular S_L problem

$X''(x)+\lambda X(x)=0$, $X'(0)=0$, $X(L)=0$

The eigenvalue-eigenfuntion are

$\lambda_n=\frac{(2n-1^2)\pi^2}{4L}$, $X_n(x)=\cos\frac{(2n-1)\pi x}{2L}$, $n=1,2,...$

Now I don't know how to generates the solution for $T_n(t)$?

Answer (score 1):

You have equation $T''(t) + \lambda T(t) = 0$. This equation has a general solution $T_n(t) = A_n \cos(2^{-1} L^{-1} (2 n -1) \pi) + B_n \sin(2^{-1} L^{-1} (2 n -1) \pi)$. Now you can write
$$u(x, t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  ((A_n \cos(2^{-1} L^{-1} (2 n -1) t \pi) + B_n \sin(2^{-1} L^{-1} (2 n -1) t \pi) \times \\ \times \cos(2^{-1} L^{-1} (2 n -1) \pi x)).$$
Now you can define $A_n$ and $B_n$ using initial conditions.

Comment: To make a clarify, $u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$?

Comment: @Miraboreasu yes